# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Tags: java, mysql, web

### mysql-connector-java-8.0.21

### mysql-6.0.11-alpha-winx64

I have searched in Google and got that the virsion of mysql can not support mysql-connector-java.But I don not know how to change the virsion of mysql-connector-java.

Comment: what version of mysql are you running?

Comment: nesides this looks like a alpha version of the driver. that is not stable

Comment: the virsion is mysql-6.0.11.servlet visit mysql

Comment: there is no Version 6 of mysql or mariadb, so you should check with SELECT version

Comment: the console shows that Server version: 6.0.11-alpha-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: oh you got a alpha version that isn't supported and very old older than 7 years, switsch to mysql server 8.0.22#